# Lower Bound Omega Notation

Tags: performance, math, big-o, asymptotic-complexity

I have to prove that some number *S* is bigger than *Ω(|V|)*, where *|V|* is the number of vertices. I read the definition of asimptotic notations, but I am still confused with the examples. Fot example, in my case, I proved that *S ≥ 1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + .... + 1/|V|. Am I done? Can someone give me similar examples of *Ω* functions?

Comment: This might better belong on the [programmers stackexchange](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/). Also, don't forget [the policy on asking homework questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The summation

> 1/1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + ... 1/n

gives the nth [harmonic number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number), denoted H<sub>n</sub>. A very useful fact is that H(n) = Θ(log n) and, more specifically, that H(n) ≥ ln n - 1. Therefore, if you've proven that S = H<sub>|V|</sub>, you've proven that S = Θ(|V| lg |V|) and therefore that S = Ω(|V|), since |V| lg |V| grows as least as fast as |V|.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot! Can I ask another question? What about 1/2 + 1/2 +...+1/2 (V times). This is also equal to Ω(|V|), right?

Comment: Well, 1/2 + 1/2 + ... + 1/2 |V| times is |V| / 2, which is Omega(|V|) :-)